# Выделить при помощи регулярных выражений кусок текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Задача: Требуется удалить весь текст который начинается с `/*` и заканчивается `*/`.

Мой вариант: `/\*(.|\n|\r)*\*/`
Если не сложно, объясните что я не правильно понимаю

- `/\*` - строка начинается с `/*`
- `(.|\n|\r)*` - любой символ
- `\*/` - пока не встретится `*/`

Comment: `*` - это специальный символ, обозначает 0 и более повторений символа. значит `/*`означает 0 и более косых, т.е. реагирует по сути на что угодно. ставьте перед `*` обратную косую

Comment: Я понимаю, не правильно написал просто.  Я подразумеваю (.|\n|\r)* - как любой символ, любое количество раз. Т.е. по русски все выражение как: Все что начинается с /* (/\*) после чего может идти что угодно (.|\n|\r)* пока не встретится */ (\*/). Вот тут я имею ввиду, что я не правильно понимаю?

Comment: ну тогда у вас в принципе все верно, хотя как подсказывают в ответе вы можете применить флаг 's' у выражения и тогда точка будет обозначать любые символы включая переводы кареток

Comment: @Mike, работает только если поставить знак "?".
Т.е. как я понимаю после /* любой символ любое количество раз ,* повторяющийся 0 или 1 раз (?) пока не будет */. Я вот не совсем понимаю почему нужен знак "?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
$text = preg_replace( '#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $text );
```

Perl:

```
$text =~ s#/\*.*?\*/##sg;
```

---

> Я вот не совсем понимаю почему нужен знак "?"

См. ["Жадные и ленивые квантификаторы"](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy), например, или что ещё найдётся в **любом руководстве по регекспам** про "жадность" регулярных выражений, это основы основ.

Если коротко, то при таком варианте: `s#/\*.*\*/##sg` будет захвачена и удалена вся строка до **последнего** найденого `*/`, и вот это:

```
"aaa /* bbb\n */ /**/ ccc\nddd /* eee\n */ fff"
```

превратится в:

```
"aaa  fff"
```

"Ленивый" же вариант будет искать до **первого** совпадения, и эта же строка превратится в:

```
"aaa  ccc\nddd  fff"
```

Comment: Т.е. как я понимаю после /* любой символ любое количество раз ,* повторяющийся 0 или 1 раз (?) пока не будет */. Я вот не совсем понимаю почему нужен знак "?"

Comment: @AntonPopov, см. дополнение к ответу.